# Use Salesforce Incremental Load component in Matillion for an existing table

Tags: salesforce, matillion

Salesforce incremental load component asks for a target table with prefix. But what if I want to use this component for an existing table.

It gives us a support to add table prefix, but I need to add an existing table.

The expectation is that, I don't want to reload all the data to a new table as I have a lot of queries based on the existing table, hence I'm looking for an incremental way to load data from salesforce in an existing table using Matillion.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like it to move it to a different structure then you can load the salesforce data into a stage table, process them and append it to the existing table...